# Why is my Cu2O Cuprous Oxide Not Red

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

A thin film sample of polycrystalline Copper(I) Oxide (Cuprous Oxide, $\ce{Cu2O}$) on quartz looks reddish in the center but bluish/grayish at the sides where the film is thicker.

The same thin film on a Silicon Oxide wafer looks greyish, with a slight tint of blue.

XPS analysis shows that the bulk of the film contains no traces of Copper(II) that can be detected within the instrument's detection limit ($\pu{0.1-0.5 at.\%}$?).

The $\ce{Cu2O}$ film is grown by CVD using a metal-organic precursor and water.

What can be causing the gray color of the $\ce{Cu2O}$? Can it be the morphology/porousity of the $\ce{Cu2O}$? If it is trace amounts of contaminants, what are some good guesses?

Comment: The Merck Index says of Cu2O: _Color may be yellow, red or brown depending on the method of preparation and particle size._ I don't know if your greyish color on the silicon oxide wafer could really be a pale yellow; it seems like a long-shot from your description. The slight tint of blue seems like it must be from oxidation to some form of Cu(II). Some Cu(II) complexes can be pretty intensely blue (although more commonly are green), so that you might see it at levels below the XPS DL. Anyway, there's a couple long-shot ideas on your interesting/difficult problem. And welcome to Chemistry.SE!

Comment: Maybe you are not seeing the bulk color of the oxide but light interference effects.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_interference.

Comment: @OscarLanzi The film is about 500-1000 nm thick, probably not light interference effects?

Comment: Not sure if this is correct, but while the $\ce{Cu2O}$ is being made, a certain amount of black-colored $\ce{CuO}$ may also have formed.

Comment: @Athena of the 500-1000nm thickness is true, yes that's a little thick for interference.  Was an idea.